# MySQL SELECT is not returning values in correct way and google line graph is not showing in desired way

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization, linechart

I am quite new here and asking question for first time, So I don't know how to ask question, But I need help of your's.

[Image of google line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fMtj.png)
[image]

I have 2 problems in the above graph.

**1.** I am getting repeated dates for views from my database and is display in the graph as above marked as **1** and **2**.

**2.** The dates are not aligned properly with dates and is marked as **3** in above image and also months are not shown some times as visible in the image.

**Help me please. Thank's in Advance**

**php & MySQL Code**

```
function AdminViews()
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }
    $out_query = "SELECT count(ip_address) AS count, date(visit_date_time) as visit_date_time FROM db_views WHERE user_id = id GROUP BY visit_date_time ORDER BY visit_date_time LIMIT 30 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$out_query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}
```

**Google Graph Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Date', 'Views']
        <?php
        $results = $ClassName->AdminViews();
        if(!empty($results)){
            foreach($results as $row) {
                $vDate = str_replace("-",", ",$row['visit_date_time']);
                echo ",[new Date('".$vDate."'),".$row['count']."]";
            }
        } ?> ]);

        var options = {
            pointSize: 5,
            legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
            hAxis: { format: 'MMM dd, yyyy', gridlines: {count: -1, color: '#fff'} },
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("barChart"));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    } </script>
```

**At Browser Js comes like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Date', 'Views']
        ,[new Date('2017, 01, 01'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 02'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 03'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 04'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 05'),7],[new Date('2017, 01, 06'),5],[new Date('2017, 01, 07'),5],[new Date('2017, 01, 07'),3],[new Date('2017, 01, 08'),3],[new Date('2017, 01, 08'),4],[new Date('2017, 01, 09'),2],[new Date('2017, 01, 10'),2],[new Date('2017, 01, 10'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 11'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 12'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 13'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 14'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 15'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 16'),6],[new Date('2017, 01, 17'),10],[new Date('2017, 01, 18'),30],[new Date('2017, 01, 19'),3],[new Date('2017, 01, 20'),3] ]);

        var options = {
            pointSize: 5,
            legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
            hAxis: { format: 'MMM dd, yyyy', gridlines: {count: -1, color: '#fff'} },
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("barChart"));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you output the raw result of your query to diagnose whether the problem is in the query or the view? 

Also, I am not sure what this 'user_id = id ' part of your query is trying to do, I assume one of these should be a variable passed in.

Comment: I think it's confusing in this instance to give DATE() an alias identical to the column name. Also LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless- even when a GROUP BY clause is present

Comment: @gwnp Yes I did the problem of displaying same date multiple time is not due to jquery. It came after replacing column name 'visit_date_time ' with 'date(visit_date_time) as visit_date_time' in the SELECT query.

Comment: What is the datatype of visit_date_time in the database? I assume date_time and that is why you are trying to format it only to a date, correct?

Comment: @gwnp This graph is a part of dash board, So user id is the id of user whose monthly views is to be displayed.

Comment: Your group by clause is not casting 'visit_date_time' to DATE and therefore is taking the full timestamp into account. If you look at the data for those problematic days, you will have multiple rows on those days but with slightly different time stamps

Comment: @Strawberry I am not very good in database stuff. So help me if you can. visit_date_time column is set to datetime and I only need date to be displayed in the graph.

Comment: Just call it something else

Comment: Yes @gwnp it's datetime, you are correct. And yes in various rows date is same but time is differrent. How to correct it.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry I cant get it . Please Describe.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your help my 1'st problem is solved.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that you receive in this loop before and after your processing. I think this is where the problem is.

foreach($results as $row) {
                $vDate = str_replace("-",", ",$row['visit_date_time']);
                echo ",[new Date('".$vDate."'),".$row['count']."]";
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group by also needs to cast the datetime to a Date, otherwise you will see in your data that you have multiple entries for the same day but slightly different timestamps, this will give you the multiple nodes.

Change this:

```
  ... GROUP BY visit_date_time ORDER BY visit_date_time ...
```

To this:

```
 ...  GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time) ORDER BY visit_date_time ...
```

That should do the trick.

**EDIT**

For your second issue, count: -1 --> means automatic alignment of grid lines which produces the undesirable result here.

Change this:

```
var options = {
        pointSize: 5,
        legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
        hAxis: { format: 'MMM dd, yyyy', gridlines: {count: -1, color: '#fff'} },
        vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
    };
```

To this (as you figured out):

```
var options = {
            pointSize: 5,
            legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
            hAxis: { slantedText: 'true', format: 'MMM dd', gridlines: {count: 10, color: 'none'} },
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
        };
```

Disclaimer: The second answer came from OP himself as I wasn't sure.

Comment: I can't upvote. my reputation is not that much to upvote.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about the other one, sorry. I might not be able to answer that part, but I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok here is the solution I found**

**1.** Change

```
 ... GROUP BY visit_date_time ORDER BY visit_date_time ...
```

to this as suggested by @gwnp

```
...  GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time) ORDER BY visit_date_time ...
```

And

**2.** Change

```
var options = {
        pointSize: 5,
        legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
        hAxis: { format: 'MMM dd, yyyy', gridlines: {count: -1, color: '#fff'} },
        vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
    };
```

to this

```
var options = {
            pointSize: 5,
            legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
            hAxis: { slantedText: 'true', format: 'MMM dd', gridlines: {count: 10, color: 'none'} },
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 }
        };
```

count: -1 --> means automatic alignment of grid lines which produces the undesirable result here.